# SAS: How to sort words within a variable in alphabetic order?

Tags: sorting, sas

I want to have the following:

```
    data animals;
      length string_in $50;
      infile datalines dlm=",";
      input string_in;
      datalines;
    rattlesnake honeybadger
    lion eagle shark gorilla
    mouse ape horse
    ;
    run;


      data animals_sorted;
        set animals;

        /* magic happens*/

        put string_in;
      run;


Output:
  string_in: honeybadger rattlesnake
  string_in: eagle gorilla lion shark 
  string_in: ape horse mouse
```

What kind of magic do you have to enter here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any SAS functions to sort the words in strings but SAS can sort the values of variables in an ARRAY.

```
data animals;
   length string_in $50;
   infile datalines dlm=",";
   input string_in;
   datalines;
rattlesnake honeybadger
lion eagle shark gorilla
mouse ape horse
;;;;
   run;
data animals_sorted;
   set animals;
   array animals[10] $32 _temporary_;
   call missing(of animals[*]);
   do i = 1 to dim(animals) until(p eq 0);
      call scan(string_in,i,p,l);
      animals[i] = substrn(string_in,p,l);
      end;
   call sortc(of animals[*]);
   length string_out $50;
   string_out = catx(' ',of animals[*]);
   drop i p l;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: You might be able to simplify it even further with the `sortc` routine. I didn't have much luck though; I kept getting blank spaces if the array was too large.

Comment: @StuSztukowski I am using SORTC(of animals[*]).  It does sort the blank array elements first but any extra spaces are removed by CATX

Comment: Oh I see it now! I missed it :)